# Function to return tuples throws error on frontend

Tags: solidity, metamask, frontend

I have similar functions like this and they work fine:

```
    function getBarsOfParticipant() external view returns (uint256[], uint16[], bool[]) {
    uint256[] barIds = participantToBarIds[msg.sender];

    uint256[] memory ids = new uint256[](barIds.length);
    uint16[] memory lengths = new uint16[](barIds.length);
    bool[] memory forSale = new bool[](barIds.length);

    for (uint16 i = 0; i <= barIds.length; i++) {
        Bar storage bar = bars[barIds[i]];
        ids[i] = barIds[i];
        lengths[i] = bar.length;
        forSale[i] = bar.forSale;
    }

    return (ids, lengths, forSale);
}
```

Although the above code compiles, I always get this error at the front-end:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Refer the following question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52197/metamask-remix-ide-cannot-create-an-account-error-internal-json-rpc-error

Answer (score 0):

I think that you cannot return the tuple of array like this `(uint256[], uint16[], bool[])`

Just return an index of each element lile `(uint256, uint16, bool)`; so you need to return length of the array and iterate in the dapp to get all the data.

Comment: Pretty sure you can return multiple arrays. No idea what's wrong however.

Comment: oh, you're right! But it seems very pain for front-end

https://medium.com/coinmonks/solidity-tutorial-returning-structs-from-public-functions-e78e48efb378